# how to plus three tables' value together?

Tags: mysql

for example, I have three tables:
table1:

```
+-------+
| count |
+-------+
|     1 |
|     1 |
|     1 |
|     0 |
+-------+
```

table2 :

```
+-------+
| count |
+-------+
|     2 |
|     0 |
+-------+
```

table3:

```
+-------+
| count |
+-------+
|     0 |
|     1 |
|     3 |
+-------+
```

Now I want to calculate table1+table2+table3. Because table1 has 4 rows,table2 has 2 rows, table3 has 3 rows, I want the final result table only have 2 rows, the minimum num of rows of these 3 tables.
So I hope get this:

```
+-------+
| count |
+-------+
|     3 |
|     2 |
+-------+
```

How could I do?Thanks for everyone's help!

Actually, I have more than 3 tables and I don't know the minimum num of rows in all these tables. Therefore, I cannot just do 'limit 2'.

Comment: How are you calculating the resulting numbers?

Comment: Why 3 and 2? Why not 9 and -7? Where did the 3 and 2 come from?

Comment: 3 and 2 etc is the num of time bins. I have  time series, for example, 3 means 20:00:00 appears twice, 3 means 20:00:01 appears 3 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

obtain the sum of first two rows only and ignore the remaining in your query and limit the records with limit keyword like this,

```
 select p.count+q.count+r.count as count from table1 p,table2 q,table3 r limit 2;
```

`Update:`

you can know the no. of records in a table with the following command in mysql,

```
 select count(*) from table1;
```

determine the minimum no. of records and place this value as limit.

you can list the available tables like this,

```
 show tables;
```

Comment: Actually, I have more than 3 tables and I don't know the minimum num of rows in all these tables.